# rm: cannot remove ‘folder’: Device or resource busy docker bind mount

Tags: docker

I had a folder bind mount, then commited my image, then I removed the volume mount. Now the folder is still there (but empty) and refuses to delete. I tried:

```
$ docker exec -it --privileged --user root f105b6bfec00 rm -R Desktop/app
$ rm: cannot remove ‘Desktop/app’: Device or resource busy

$ docker exec -it --privileged --user root f105b6bfec00 lsof +D Desktop/app
$
```

edit: this is the docker-compose file I used:

```
version: '2'
services:
  centos-vnc-node: 
    image: davedm/centos-node-chrome-vnc:latest
    volumes:
      - .:/headless/Desktop/app
    ports:
      - 6901:6901
      - 5901:5901   
    environment:
      - VNC_PW=password12345678
```

Comment: Can you share the `Dockerfile` you used to build your image and the relevant `docker run` command(s)?

Comment: @DavidMaze this is the image https://hub.docker.com/r/davedm/centos-node-chrome-vnc

Comment: It's a flaw somewhere in the linux kernel, not docker.
mount --bind causes it